# Problems when starting MongoDB with > 1023 FDs

Tags: mongodb

We are running a 3 node replSet with lots of data and currently have more than 1500 datafiles.

When restarting MongoDB instance we now run into the following problem:

```
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 [initandlisten] create collection local.startup_log { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true }
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 [initandlisten] command local.$cmd command: { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:75 543ms
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 [initandlisten] info PageFaultRetryableSection will not yield, already locked upon reaching
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 [initandlisten] insert local.startup_log ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0  0ms
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 [initandlisten] fd limit hard:550000 soft:550000 max conn: 440000
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 [initandlisten] ERROR: socket 1203 is higher than 1023; not supported
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 [initandlisten] now exiting
Thu May 30 12:11:20.326 dbexit:
```

After lots of googling, it looks like it has something to do with a FD_SETSIZE limitation to 1024. But ulimit -n is set to 550000, as you can see in the log.

I don't manage to bring the instance up again...does someone maybe has a hint for me?

Thanks, Oliver

Comment: Which operating system are you running the server on?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8521) which may apply depending on version.

Comment: It's running on RHEL 6.3. MongoDB Version is v2.4.3, git version: fe1743177a5ea03e91e0052fb5e2cb2945f6d95f.

Comment: I just filed an issue @10gen https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9818

Answer (score 0):

Source code for this error message is here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4.1/src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp#L205

File descriptor is here compared to FD_SETSIZE, which is defined in header files to 1024. I see no easy way how to change this value by configuring anything (operating system, ulimits...).

Are you using the latest MongoDB version? Looking at the MongoDB issues, there were some changes to lower the number of used file descriptors by not opening all files at startup - see link in Joachim Isaksson's comment.

Comment: Thank you guys, not opening all files at startup sounds good so far. But i'm note sure if this has been implemented with bump 2.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

We are debugging this here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9818 and plan to fix ASAP in the next release.